# Conference board typesetting

Tags: posters

I've been working on some research since the past year or so and the time has come to present it at an exhibition.

I need a board approximately 36" wide, 44" high - typical conference board. How would I typeset something like this in LaTeX? Any classes specifically for posters?

Things I need:

- Needs to be very easy and quick to learn - I'm working with very little time.
- Simple insertion of graphics
- Works well with PDF.

That's about it. Suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). [`beamerposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) is right down your alley :)

Comment: For example: either http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=poster or final rescaling ordinary LaTeX document (driver dependent).

Comment: Do you have a printer into which you can feed material that's 36" wide?